# Dpylr's recode function multiple-to-1 R

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I would like an easier way to recode vectors. Specifically I'm wondering if there is a way to pass vectors to a function like `dplyr`'s `recode`. I understand the basics of quasiquotation but don't quite get how to incorporate the `=`.

```
library(tidyverse)

vec1 <- rep(LETTERS[1:7],7)

#standard way
vec2 <- recode(vec1, 
               "A" = "Value1",
               "B" = "Value2",
               "C" = "Value3",
               "D" = "Value4",
               "E" = "Value5",
               "F" = "Value6",
               "G" = "Value7"
               )

vec3 <- recode(vec1,
               "A" = "Value1",
               "B" = "Value1",
               "C" = "Value2",
               "D" = "Value2",
               .default = "Value other"
               )
```

I'd like to do the following

```
vec3 <- some.function(vec1,
               c("A", "B") = "Value1",
               c("C", "D") = "Value2",
               .default = "Value other"
               )
```

I have a solution but can't figure out how to incorporate a function with `...` and `=`

```
do.call(dplyr::recode, 
        c(list(vec1), 
        setNames(rep("Value1",length(val1)), val1), 
        setNames(rep("Value2",length(val2)), val2)))
```

I also have figured out a way to pass two vectors and rename all the variables.

```
recode.by.vectors <- function(x, current.names, new.names){
  do.call(dplyr::recode, c(list(x), setNames(new.names, current.names)))
}
```

Lastly, I'm aware of a base solution.

```
vec3 <- vec1
val1 <- c("A", "B")
val2 <- c("C", "D")
vec3[vec1 %in% val1] <- "Value1"
vec3[vec1 %in% val2] <- "Value2"
vec3[!vec1 %in% c(val1,val1)] <- "Value other"
```

but am unaware to how in incorporate the assignment carried out here into a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `case_when` from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

vec1 <- rep(LETTERS[1:7],7)

vec2 <- case_when(
    vec1 %in% c("A", "B")    ~ "Value1",
    vec1 %in% c("C", "D")    ~ "Value2",
    TRUE                     ~ "Value other"
  ) 
head(vec2)
# [1] "Value1"      "Value1"      "Value2"      "Value2"      "Value other" "Value other"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `forcats` package (also included in the `tidyverse` package)

```
library(forcats)

vec1 <- rep(LETTERS[1:7], 7)

fct_collapse(vec1,
             Value1 = c("A", "B"),
             Value2 = c("C", "D"),
             `Value other` = c("E", "F", "G"))
```

This is a little cumbersome if you have lots of categories to put into `Value other`, but with a secondary step, you can simplify it a little bit

```
fct_collapse(vec1,
             Value1 = c("A", "B"),
             Value2 = c("C", "D")) %>% 
  fct_other(keep = c("Value1", "Value2"),
            other_level = "Value other")
```